# Set error from angular directive to control in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have migrated a directive from angular js to angular 4, which formats and validates the phone number. In angular js I was setting the error to form for that control with below code:

```
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            if (viewValue && viewValue.toString().length != 0 && viewValue.toString().length < 14) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('phnLen', false);
            } else {
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('phnLen', true);
            }
            return viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0, 10);
        });
```

but in angular 4 I am not able to find a way to notify the form about error for that control. So that we have correct value in form.valid attribute. Can anybody please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create reactive form. and give validation like that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/email-phone-validation-reactive

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom validator and attached it to your `FormControl` Validators, as like how we attach validators in AngularJS.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

function validatePhone(c: FormControl) {
  const viewValue = c.value;
  return viewValue && viewValue.toString().length != 0 && viewValue.toString().length < 14) ? null: {
    phnLen: {
      valid: false
    }
  }
}

@Directive({
  // for template driven form with ngModel
  selector: '[validatePhone][ngModel]',
  // for model driven form with formControlName
  //selector: '[validatePhone][formControlName]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useValue: validatePhone, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class PhoneValidator {} // Add this directive in declarations.
```

When it comes to usage you can use it like below

```
<input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" ngModel validatePhone>
//OR
<input type="tel" formControlName="phoneNumber" validatePhone>
```

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Parkar, thanks for reply. Can you please tell me how to attach it from directive because in directive only I am validating the inputs.